# Discord.js - While loop for a message

Tags: javascript, loops, discord, discord.js

I am new to JavaScript, I decided to  start with discord.js to make my first projects, I was trying to make a spam command as a challenge, but this doesn't seem to work

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content == 'spam') {
    while (true) {
      msg.channel.send('@everyone');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this as your bot will most likely hit a rate limit quickly and you're basically just spamming the discord API

Comment: No, the bot doesn't send any message

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First things first you shouldn't do this, you're basically abusing the api and will end up getting rate limited

secondly, you need to await, keep in mind dont spam :D

```
cleint.on('message', async msg => {
    let spam = false;
    if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === 'spam') spam = true;
    else if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === 'stop spam') spam = false;
    while (spam == true)
        await msg.channel.send('spamming is bad');
});
```

Comment: That simply... doesn't work at all. Theoretically the bot would just keep sending the same message over and over. The 'stop spam' part is useless.

Comment: @user15517071 lol, he wanted to spam and asked for help, gave him the answer and asked him to think before spamming on a large scale :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I fixed, if you're interested this is how I did it:

```
client.on("message", async (msg) => {
    if (msg.content === "spam") {
        while (true) {
            await msg.channel.send("@everyone");
        }
    }
})
```